# GTK get slider value

Tags: gtk, gtk3

How to get slider value in GTK?

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

GtkWidget *speed_sld,*speed_label;

static void transmit (GtkWidget *widget,gint *data)
{
  float val = gtk_scale_get_digits(data);
  g_print("Val is %f \n",val);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkBuilder *builder;
    GtkWidget *window;


    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    builder = gtk_builder_new ();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "./ECU.glade", NULL);

    window = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "window1"));
    //g_signal_connect (window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK (on_window_destroy), NULL);

    speed_sld = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "scale1"));
    speed_label = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "label1"));

    g_signal_connect (speed_sld, "value-changed", G_CALLBACK (transmit), NULL);

    gtk_widget_show_all (window);
    gtk_main ();
}
```

How can i print slider value in transmit function?I tried printing data,*data etc how can i get the values inside function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

data is a pointer to whatever data was provided in g_signal_connect (you provided NULL), so that doesn't make sense.

I'm guessing you got confused by looking at GtkScale documentation: remember that you also need to look at the parent widgets API, in this case [GtkRange](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkRange.html). This should work:

```
static void transmit (GtkRange *range, gpointer data)
{
  g_print ("current value is %f\n", gtk_range_get_value (range));
}
```